# str[index + 1] returns undefined within for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Why does this occur?

```js
let str = 'sSAo'
console.log(str[0], str[3]) // all good

for (let i in str) {
    // why str[i+1] is undefined ???
    console.log(i, str[i], str[i+1])
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `for..in` loops iterate over the *property names* of the object. But property names are always *strings*, not numbers. Hence, for example, on the first iteration:

```
str[i+1]
```

evaluates to

```
str['0'+1]
```

which is

```
str['01']
```

Instead, cast `i` to a `Number` first:

```js
let str = 'abcd'

for (let i in str) {
    console.log(i, str[i], str[Number(i)+1])
}
```

Comment: You get the upvote for being the only one who explains *why* `i` is a string, instead of just showing how to fix it.

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `i+1` will not plus the value as you expected,the value will be `01,11,21,31`,that's the reason for it,you need to use `parseInt()` to do it,

```js
let str = 'sSAo'
console.log(str[0], str[3]) // all good

for (let i in str) {
    // why str[i+1] is undefined ???
    console.log(i, str[i], str[parseInt(i)+1]);//but the last one will still be undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`i` is actually a string, so `+` will concatenate 1 to its value.

You can prepend it with `+` to convert the variable to a number:

```js
let str = 'sSAo'
console.log(str[0], str[3]) // all good

for (let i in str) {
    // why str[i+1] is undefined ???
    console.log(i + 1, +i + 1, str[i], str[+i + 1])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `parseInt()` as below:

```js
let str = 'sSAo'
console.log(str[0], str[3]) // all good

for (let i in str) {
    // why str[i+1] is undefined ???
    console.log(i, str[i], str[parseInt(i)+1])
}
```

In this case, only last looping time undefined will be shown. I hope you that is because of the reason that its not in `str`.